# Eclipse not showing colored textview in Graphical Layout

Tags: android, eclipse, textview, android-studio

I am using Eclipse with the corresponding Android SDK and plugin to develop Android applications.

When editing a layout I am presented with both an XML view and a Graphical Layout view for the layout. In my layout I have several TextView controls/views.

By default they display with the black foreground color which is just fine. However, my application uses some predefined colors (foreground) for some of these views. For that I have defined the colors in the XML so that I can select them in the Text Color property of the IDE.

The issue arises when I try to use the Text View property of the Eclipse IDE to change the default color of the TextView. As soon as I select a color (for example @color/red) then the foreground color of the TextView is always changed to WHITE regardless of which color I chose, even with Black it becomes white.

Now that seems to me like a problem. Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Try using the hexadecimal of the color, for the red color it would be #ff0000.

Comment: I have defined them as indicated with ARGB.

    <resources>
      <color name="black_overlay">#66000000</color>
      <color name="red">#00FF0000</color>
      <color name="green">#0000FF00</color>
      <color name="blue">#000000FF</color>
      <color name="black">#00000000</color>
      <color name="purple">#00B53FFF</color>
      <color name="cyan">#0021CBFF</color>
    </resources>